# Where can I get old versions of HP bios?

Tags: bios, hp-pavilion

Since I've updated my HP Pavilion g6-1c40ca's bios from F.44 to F.49, putting my computer into sleep mode and hibernating gives me a blue screen of death, and closing the lid when plugged in disconnects the computer from the network.

I've tried finding the old version of the bios on HP's update site, but that only gives me bioses up to F.48, which still has the same problem. I also tried using the HP bios restore tool, by holding Windows Key + B + Power Button for 3 seconds, but after a few seconds, the caps lock LED starts flashing and nothing else happens.

Where could I download the old version of the bios?

Comment: It would help to include the full name of the laptop model. For example, mine is HP ENVY 15-3040nr. I easily found a nice archive of drivers [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/drivers-hp-envy-15-3xxx-envy-17-3xxx-intel.630212/) for my laptop. You could probably do the same.

Comment: There is an F.46 version here you could try: http://hpnotebookdrivers.com/hp-pavilion-g6-1c40ca-notebook-pc-windows-7-64-bit-drivers/ Not sure how different it would be from F.48 or close to F.44.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are welcome to [browse the HP FTP site](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq) where they keep all softpaq updates, there are a bunch but I would start at folder SP55501-56000 and work your way up the number sequence.

SP55938 states:
 Fixes an intermittent issue where repeatedly switching between sleep and hibernate modes and rebooting cause the system to stop responding or to display a black screen error.

Bios update will always have a related CVA file, so skip the SP's that dont have one, read the cva to see if it is a bios update, what number it is and what hardware it applies to, you should be able to find older versions of your bios using this method. Some versions of bios files are removed from FTP because they are problematic.

Most HP's do not allow you to install and older bios version because it can brick your PC in some cases.

Do Not apply a bios update that is not for your hardware model.